# Using XMLTABLE to parse CDATA section of SOAP

Tags: xml, oracle, web-services, soap

I'm following the example in this [thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3788694?start=0&tstart=0) to learn how to parse the CDATA section of a SOAP response using XMLTABLE. Database is Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition 11.2.0.4.0.

I modified the SOAP response that I need to parse just so I could have a query that works, similar to the example I was looking at.

So this is what is working ok, albeit with a slightly simplified response envelope:

```
CREATE TABLE xml_tab (xml_data xmltype);

DECLARE l
l_xmltype xmltype;

BEGIN

SELECT xmltype('<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:sawsoap="urn://oracle.bi.webservices/v6">  
<soap:Body>    
<sawsoap:executeSQLQueryResult>      
<sawsoap:return xsi:type="sawsoap:QueryResults">        
<sawsoap:rowset><![CDATA[<Data><Row><Column0>1200</Column0><Column1>East Region</Column1></Row><Row><Column0>3000</Column0><Column1>West Region</Column1></Row></Data>]]></sawsoap:rowset>        
<sawsoap:queryID/>        
<sawsoap:finished>true</sawsoap:finished>      
</sawsoap:return>    
</sawsoap:executeSQLQueryResult>  
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>') INTO l_xmltype FROM dual ;

INSERT INTO xml_tab VALUES(l_xmltype);

END;
```

And this query returns the results I want:

```
SELECT B2.*  
   FROM 
   xml_tab x,
   XMLTable(  
         XMLNamespaces(  
           'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS "SOAP-ENV"  
            ,'urn://oracle.bi.webservices/v6' AS  "sawsoap"                
          )  
        , 'SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/sawsoap:executeSQLQueryResult/sawsoap:return/sawsoap:rowset'  
          passing    x.XML_DATA 
          columns Row1 clob path '.'  
       ) A1,
        XMLTable(  
         '/Data/Row'  
         passing xmlparse(document A1.Row1)  
         columns    
         Amount number PATH 'Column0',
         Region varchar2(60) PATH 'Column1'
       ) B2;



AMOUNT REGION                                                     
  ---------- ------------------------------------------------------------
  1200 East Region                                                  
  3000 West Region
```

Unfortunately the actual SOAP response that I need to parse looks like this:

```
truncate table xml_tab;

 DECLARE
  l_xmltype xmltype;
BEGIN
  SELECT xmltype('<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:sawsoap="urn://oracle.bi.webservices/v6">
  <soap:Body>
    <sawsoap:executeSQLQueryResult>
      <sawsoap:return xsi:type="sawsoap:QueryResults">
        <sawsoap:rowset><![CDATA[<rowset xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset" ><Row><Column0>01200</Column0><Column1>East Region</Column1></Row><Row><Column0>3000</Column0><Column1>West Region</Column1></Row></rowset>]]></sawsoap:rowset>
        <sawsoap:queryID/>
        <sawsoap:finished>true</sawsoap:finished>
      </sawsoap:return>
    </sawsoap:executeSQLQueryResult>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>')
  INTO l_xmltype
  FROM dual ;
  INSERT INTO xml_tab VALUES
    (l_xmltype
    );
END;
```

Because of this bit, rowset xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset", my code no longer works and I don't know how to get past this. If anyone can suggest modifications to my query that will successfully parse this SOAP response I would greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your secound sopa request has invalid xml in cdata.

```
SELECT A1.Row1  
   FROM 
   xml_tab x,
   XMLTable(  
         XMLNamespaces(  
           'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS "SOAP-ENV"  
            ,'urn://oracle.bi.webservices/v6' AS  "sawsoap"                
          )  
        , 'SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/sawsoap:executeSQLQueryResult/sawsoap:return/sawsoap:rowset'  
          passing    x.XML_DATA 
          columns Row1 clob path '.'  
       ) A1
```

Returns

```
<rowset xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset" >
  <Row>
    <Column0>01200/Column0>   --<-- invalid tag column0 isn't closed
    <Column1>East Region</Column1>
    </Row>
  <Row>
    <Column0>3000</Column0>
    <Column1>West Region</Column1>
    </Row>
</rowset>
```

In you 1st xml(cdata) path to `row` element is `/Data/row` in 2nd is `/rowset/row`. 
In 2nd xml(cdata) also exist declaration of default namsespace `xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset"`.

You can change path in 2nd xmltable to `'*/Row'` and get rid of xml namespace. 
  `passing xmlparse(document regexp_replace(A1.Row1,'xmlns=".*"', ''))`

```
  SELECT  B2.*
       FROM 
       xml_tab x,
       XMLTable(  
             XMLNamespaces(  
               'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS "SOAP-ENV"  
                ,'urn://oracle.bi.webservices/v6' AS  "sawsoap"                
              )  
            , 'SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/sawsoap:executeSQLQueryResult/sawsoap:return/sawsoap:rowset'  
              passing    x.XML_DATA 
              columns Row1 clob path '.'  
           ) A1
          ,
            XMLTable(  
             '/*/Row'  
            passing xmlparse(document regexp_replace(A1.Row1,'xmlns=".*"', ''))  
             columns    
            Amount number PATH 'Column0',
            Region varchar2(60) PATH 'Column1'
          ) B2;
```

Comment: Works perfectly - apologies for the missing tag in the second xml (it's fixed now in the example). And yes, I added the <Data> tag around the first to resemble the example I was working from, but the actual SOAP response includes the default namespace and the rowset tag. Thank you for your help in getting me past this hump.